# How to add duplicate record in relation entity coredata

Tags: core-data

I have two entity

1. Box
2. Items

   I want to add multiple items on same box object but when i try to add multiple(duplicate) items on same box object then its store unique object record.
   Kindly help me to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

A Core Data relationship is a set, not an array. One of the defining characteristics of a set is that it doesn't contain duplicate entries. So, you can't have the same object appear twice in the same relationship. It's hard to tell what that would even mean... A `Box` is related to an `Item` twice?

If you're trying to do this to indicate quantity (i.e. two of the same `Item` in a `Box`) you'll need a third entity type that stores the quantity and has a relationship to the `Item`. Probably something like

```
Box <---->> BoxItem <<----> ItemType
```

Here the `ItemType` replaces your `Item`, and `BoxItem` stores the quantity and relates to one `Box` and one `ItemType`. Any time you add one `ItemType` to a `Box` you create a `BoxItem` with a quantity of one. If you add another of the same type, increase the quantity.